# ggplot dateRangeInput in Rshiny

Tags: r

I am trying to make my line graph change based on the users input in the dateRangeInput widget in Rshiny. I have a column named SampleTime that has dates but every time I run the app I cannot seem to get the plot to change. I am obviously not linking this together correctly. Can anyone provide any input to this problem? Below is my code in app code in R.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)


# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("TPO Data Over Time by Valve ID and Product Type"),
    
    # Sidebar
    sidebarLayout(
        position = "left",
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(inputId = "valves",
                        label = strong("Valve ID"),
                        choices = unique(cTPO$ValveID),
                        selected = "1"),
            
            selectInput(inputId = "products",
                        label = strong("Product Type"),
                        choices = unique(cTPO$Product),
                        selected = "12OZ CAN"),
            
            dateRangeInput(inputId = "calendar",
                           label = 'Date range input: mm-dd-yyyy',
                           format = "mm-dd-yyyy",
                           start = NULL, end = NULL)),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("TPOPlot"))))

# Define server logic required to draw a line plot
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    
    output$TPOPlot <- renderPlot({
        
       
        ## Read cTPO.csv and assign
        cTPO <- read_csv("cTPO.csv")
    
        ## Get date from data
        cTPO$SampleTime <- as.Date(cTPO$SampleTime, "%m/%d/%Y")
    
         ## Create point plot of TPO by valve number and product type
        cTPO %>%
            select(                               
                ValveID,                             
                BrandName, 
                Product, 
                TPOvalue,
                CO2value,
                LogIDKey,
                SampleTime) %>%
            filter_all(all_vars(!is.na(.))) 
    
        ## Create line plot of TPO data
        cTPO %>%
            filter (ValveID == input$valves, Product == input$products) %>%
            ggplot(aes (x = SampleTime, y = TPOvalue)) +
            geom_line() +
            labs (x = "Sample Date", y ="TPO Value") +
            theme_bw()
    })
}
```

Comment: Date range will provide a vector of length 2 with two dates in it. So you can filter using `input$calendar[1]` and `input$calendar[2]`. Something like `cTPO %>% filter(SampleTime > input$calendar[1], SampleTime < input$calendar[2])`. You might have to convert input$calendar to a datetime if SampleTime is a datetime.

Comment: This was so helpful. Thank you so much! It works flawlessly. I am just starting to learn R and you have helped me immensely.